# Eslint or prettier issue help me to resolve it

Tags: vue.js

ERROR in [eslint]
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\quiz-app\src\main.js
1:27  error  Replace `'vue'` with `"vue";`              prettier/prettier
2:17  error  Replace `'./App.vue'` with `"./App.vue";`  prettier/prettier
3:20  error  Replace `'./router'` with `"./router";`    prettier/prettier
4:19  error  Replace `'./store'` with `"./store";`      prettier/prettier
6:45  error  Replace `'#app')` with `"#app");`

how to get rid of this
when i save file all "" convert into '' and then error occured
i have no eslintrc.js file**your text**

Comment: Hi @moazzam and welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/tour and maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Then revise your question. I think you will be more likely to get help after doing so.